# Show that in a ring with $u^2 = 0$, $1 + u$ is a unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I eventually worked this out through trial and error and found that $(1 + u)(1 - u) = 1$

But is there a more calculated way of determining this? I just kept trying different values until I found one that satisfied the equation, it seems a very inefficient way of solving something like this.

Comment: This is a version of a more general fact : If $u^n = 0$, then $1+u$ is a unit. Check that
$$
(1+u)(1-u + u^2 -u^3 +\ldots + (-1)^{n-1}u^{n-1}) = 1
$$

Comment: No, that's probably the best way to prove it.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Is there any name for that fact? Or a more involved theorem/proof? Or is it just a case of 'It is what it is'?

Comment: Its basic lemma about Jacobson radical. You can find it in Lams book A First course in noncommutative Rings in the chapter about Jacobson radical.

Comment: @AlgebraGuy : Not sure there is a name for it, other than "a unit + a nilpotent element is a unit" :)

Comment: "unit + nilpotent" is not always a unit. You need that the unit commutes with the nilpotent element, for example.

Comment: @Prahlad: The confusing signs are not necessary when we substitute $-u$ in the first place.

Comment: Dear @user52045 : This doesn't seem to be related to the Jacobson radical in any way... the Jacobson radical doesn't contain all nilpotents in some rings, although it does contain the central nilpotent elements. There is a similar looking thing that $1+xr$ is a unit for any $x\in J(R)$ and $r\in R$ that you might be thinking of...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember the geometric series from basic calculus:
$$\frac{1-z^n}{1-z} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k$$
It holds if $z \neq 1$, but (and this is how one proves it)
$$1-z^n = (1-z) \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k$$
always holds, and in fact this equation holds in every ring, for every ring element $z$ (and of course we may also interchange the two factors on the right, since both are polynomials in $z$ and hence commute with eath other). It follows that if $z$ is nilpotent, say $z^n=0$, then $1-z$ is a unit with inverse
$$(1-z)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k.$$
By substitution ($z \mapsto -z$), we see that also $1+z$ is a unit. These units are known as [**unipotent**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unipotent) elements.

More generally, if $I$ is an ideal of $R$ such that $R$ is complete with respect to the $I$-adic topology, and $u \in I$, then $1-u$ is invertible with
$$\frac{1}{1-u} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} u^k.$$
The usual proof of the geometric series works. For example, $1-t \in R[[t]]$ is a unit (but of course not in $R[t]$ unless $R=0$).